# Combining Data from two MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to combine data from two tables in MySQL with PHP.

I want to select all the data (id, title, post_by, content and created_at) from the "posts" table.

Then I would like to select the comment_id COUNT from the "comments" table IF the comment_id equals the posts id.

Finally, I would like to echo/print something on this order:

```
<? echo $row->title; ?>
Posted by <? echo $row->post_by; ?> on <? echo $row->created_at; ?> CST
<? echo $row->content; ?>
<? echo $row->comment_id; ?> comments | <a href="comment.php?id=<? echo $row->id; ?>">view/post comments</a>
```

I'm uncertain as to how to "combine" the data from two tables.  I have tried numerous things and have spent several evenings and have had no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, p.post_by, p.content, p.created_at, Count(c.comment_id)
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN comments c on p.post_id = c.comment_id
GROUP BY p.id, p.title, p.post_by, p.content, p.created_at
```

Comment: The left join will make sure you still return posts without any comments.  The group by will allow you to get the posts data and the comment count (an aggregation) in one query.

Comment: tehMick, Thank you so much for your quick reply. This seems to work, however, when using the following code, I am not getting a count, or anything for that matter: <? echo $row->comment_id; ?> As you probably can tell, I'm a rookie at this and am learning as I go. Thanks again for your assistance.

Comment: You'll need to alias the count in order to reference it in php:
`SELECT `...` Count(c.comment_id) AS comment_count`
Then you can use `$row->comment_count`.

Comment: TehMick,

If I wanted to add a WHERE statement to this, where would I put it?  I've used WHERE statements in the past, but am a bit confused with the JOIN.

Thanks again for your help!  I'm so appreciative!

Comment: @Nick: I always confuse myself about that as well.  The WHERE clause would go just before the GROUP BY - it always follows any join.  It allows you to filter your results *before* they are aggregated.  If you want to filter the comments you count rather than the posts, you could just add another condition to the ON clause of the join with AND: `...ON p.post_id = c.comment_id AND c.comment_by = 'Nick'`

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a join

```
select * from posts p
inner join comments c on p.post_id = c.comment_id
```

To get the count of how many comment rows you have for all posts, you can use a nested select statement:

```
select count(comment_id) from comments c 
where comment_id in (select id from posts)
```

Comment: He wants the comment_id COUNT.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but wouldn't this be two SELECT statements then?